# Precision/Repeatability issue with XArm6

Tags: robotic-arm, motor

I have a robotic setup with a XArm6 robot and camera facing up with vision algorithms.

I noticed that after a collision or power glitch the robot gets offset. X, Y and Z and angle change according to the camera even though I send the robot at the same location. After that it stayed repeatable until next collision.

A few questions:
1- What is the technical explanation behind what I'm seeing?
2- Should I expect the same behavior from more expansive brands (Universal, Doosan, ABB, ...)?
3- I wouldn't call this a repeatability issue since between collisions it is repeatable. Does this have a name?

Comment: Can you comment on the magnitude of the error?  Preferably with pics/video.  This may help narrow the issue.

Comment: It’s about +/- 3 mm offset..